# How to get number values from an html form using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know why it doesn't work:

```
html>

<form id="myForm">
<input type="number" name="thing1"> 
<input type="number" name="thing2">
<input type="number" name="thing3">
<input type="button" name="button" onclick="getData()" value="Submit">


</form>

<script>


function getData(){
     var data = [];
    data[0] = form.thing1.value;
    data[1] = form.thing2.value;
    data[2] = form.thing3.value;

 return data;   
}

var x = getData();

document.write(x[0]);


</script>


</html>
```

I've also tried to use document.getElementById but that didn't work either
I would want to use the data for further calculations so it should be in integer format.

Comment: use `parseInt(form.thing1.value)`

Comment: The `id` of the form is not `form`, it's `myForm`

Answer (score 0):

Use `id` not `name`.

```
<input type="number" id="thing1"> 
<input type="number" id="thing2">
<input type="number" id="thing3">

document.getElementById('thing1').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

`form.thing1.value` doesn't work because you don't have a variable called `form`

`getElementById` doesn't work (presumably) because the inputs don't have names.

Add `var form = document.getElementById("myForm");` to the top of your function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving names in the HTML, give **ids** for the inputs

```
<input type="number" id="thing1"> 
<input type="number" id="thing2">
<input type="number" id="thing3">
```

and then get the elements by id in the document

```
var inp1 = document.getElementById('thing1').value
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following codes. I have used `getElementsById` to get the values.

```
    <html>      
    <form id="myForm">
    <input type="number" name="thing1"> 
    <input type="number" name="thing2">
    <input type="number" name="thing3">
    <input type="button" name="button" onclick="getData()" value="Submit">


    </form>

    <script>


    function getData(){
        var data = [];
        data[0] = document.getElementsByName('thing1')[0].value;
        data[1] = document.getElementsByName('thing2')[0].value;
        data[2] = document.getElementsByName('thing3')[0].value;
        console.log(data); // Check the console for the values for every click.
    return data;   
    }

    var x = getData(); // When this is executed there will be no values in the input.



    </script>


    </html>
```